# iOS GPUImageContext.h file not found

Tags: ios

I want to use [LBBlurredImage](https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage) in my project. I do everything exactly like in instruction but I get error:

> GPUImageContext.h file not found

Do you know what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) to your project.

Comment: Well, I have it. I add this project, add target dependencies and framework.